# How to show the multiple marker on google maps Android?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have problem in my project, i don't know how to show the multiple marker on google map with latitude and longitude data from database mySql..

here the code using the array list:

```
private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
      super(marker);

      boundCenterBottom(marker);


      //i want change this, calling the data from mysql automatically
      items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.748963847316034,
                                          -73.96807193756104),
                                "UN", "United Nations"));
      items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.76866299974387,
                                          -73.98268461227417),
                                "Lincoln Center",
                                "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));
      items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.765136435316755,
                                          -73.97989511489868),
                                "Carnegie Hall",
              "Where you go with practice, practice, practice"));
      items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.70686417491799,
                                          -74.01572942733765),
                                "The Downtown Club",
                        "Original home of the Heisman Trophy"));

      populate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a class as Positions to get the attributes back

For the class of Position, call the method to retrieve the geo location points by implementing the  function using the Keywords as searching the position and return the geo -locations

Answer (score 0):

Use this class I love it: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons and it has examples.

```
SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(37.878901f * 1e6),(int)(-4.779396 * 1e6));
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello, World!", "I'm in Spain!");
.
.
.
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(37.878901f * 1e6),(int)(-4.779396 * 1e6));
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello, World!", "I'm in Spain!");

itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```